# How to transfer all SOL from one wallet to another using JS API

Tags: web3.js

I'm trying to send all SOL from one wallet to another. My main problem is that I have many wallets with a small amount of SOL so I want to save as much SOL as I can.

```
async function transferToMain(){
  const fromKeypair = Keypair.generate();
  const toKeypair = Keypair.generate();
  const gasFee = 0; // Is there a safe amount?
  const lamports =  await connection.getBalance(fromKeypair.publicKey) - gasFee; 
  console.log(`FROM ${fromKeypair} TO ${toKeypair} AMOUNT ${lamports} BALANCE ${lamports + gasFee}`)
  const transaction = new Transaction().add(SystemProgram.transfer({
    fromPubkey: fromKeypair.publicKey,
    toPubkey: toKeypair.publicKey,
    lamports: lamports
  }));
  const signature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
    connection,
    transaction,
    [fromKeypair]
  )
  console.log('SIGNATURE: '+ signature)
  
}
```

Trying to send SOL exactly equal to balance will yield

```
SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Transaction leaves an account with a lower balance than rent-exempt minimum
```

I've tried to add a small amount for transfer fee, but it is prone to failure because  gas fee fluctuates.
The source code shows that it just takes BigInt/ number type for the lamport argument - and doesn't handle special input : [transfer](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/0f27496/src/programs/system.ts#L777), [transferParams](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/0f27496/src/programs/system.ts#L36).

On the CLI, we can do something like

```
$solana transfer --from <FROM_ADDRESS> <RECIPIENT_ADDRESS> ALL
```

I'm wondering if there is a similar way to do it on the JS API?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

1. https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getAccountInfoAndContext and get the size of the account.
2. https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption to see how much needed for rent exempt.